# How can i use SWT Shells and JavaFx stages in the same Thread?

Tags: javafx, swt

I have an application with a JavaFX Stage and a SWT Shell. There are controles in the JavaFX stage that alter properties of the SWT widgets in the Shell and some JaveFX controles that are informed about changes in the SWT widgets.
Of course, everything with JavaFX has to happen in the JavaFx application thread and everything with SWT widgets has to happen in the SWT Thread.

I first tried to have one thread for each and switch thread when ever i switch the context. this was very annoying and i decided to no longer follow this approach.
Instead Create the SWT window inside the JavaFX Application thread so that the two UIs run on the same thread. Everything works fine this way except one thing

```
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
```

SWT need this snippet, otherwise non of the widgets react on events and SWT needs this to be on the same thread like everything else too. But this snippet is blocking, so as soon as i use it JavaFX freezes.

I know having SWT and JavaFX windows is probably a very odd use case but is there a solution to this?

Just to clarify:

- i don't want JavaFX Nodes inside SWT Widgets
- I don't want SWT Widgets inside JavaFX Nodes.

Comment: I doubt that many people know enough about both JavaFX and SWT to say for sure but I think this is probably not possible. Note that on macOS SWT also requires to run on the very first thread started making this even more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWT and JavaFX can operate in the same thread. A little trick to achieve that is to create a dummy *FXCanvas* instance before calling any other JavaFX code. FXCanvas is normally used to embed FX controls into SWT; even if you don't need that, the FXCanvas constructor initializes JavaFX properly to work in SWT interoperability mode.

The below code snippet demonstrated an SWT shell and a JavaFX stage working together. Both SWT and JavaFX button click handlers execute on JavaFX Application thread.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        new FXCanvas(new Shell(), SWT.NONE);

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Button fxbutton = new Button("JavaFX button");
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxbutton);
        fxbutton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> System.out.println("FX event, thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button swtbutton = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        swtbutton.setText("SWT button");
        swtbutton.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> System.out.println("SWT event, thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        shell.open();
        shell.pack();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works. Since i asked for a solution i've switched to a different implementation but i will keep your solution in mind. thx

Comment: As this works as a solution to the question, would you accept the answer?

Comment: Its done. i'm quite new to so so i was not aware about accepting answers.